# Why does a body take hyperbolic path/any other type path if projected upwards?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, escape-velocity

I have learnt that when a body is projected with a velocity greater than escape velocity it escapes along a hyperbolic path, if it is equal to escape velocity a parabolic path. If the velocity is betweeb escape and critical velocity than it orbits in a elliptical path. I want to know why is it the case and is there a way to prove it say mathematically?
If yes can someone tell me what do to do prove it?

Comment: To the person who gave the link of derivations thank you!
The derivation with cartesian coordinates helped a lot